# Is it convenient to use 3rd Parties Cloud Services to store data?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, cloud-storage

Is it good to rely your complete application success on backened services such as Parse or Cloud42 ? Or what would be the best solution ?

To handle one itself the application's database remote storage or to rely on 3rd parties SDKs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is, of course, "it depends".

It's essential your read the TOS of your provider, ensure your application data will be really yours, that it's always available and that nobody else will mess with it.

Basically, ensure your provider met the CIA triad, Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability.

Personally, I would always prefer to be responsible of my own environment, or use at least some VPS for it (Amazon solutions are nice).

Of course, third party solutions have some good sides, being simplicity and cost the most importants. If you are starting a project for zero, I think you can probably rely on third party apps and focus on making a successful App.

Once you reach your critical mass, you will have the resources to migrate to a own solution, you probably should focus on some other stuff before that.

Comment: Quite specific answer, thanks.